# Why can I not destroy a tkinter interface using a function that I defined?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button, global-variables

I am trying to have a button on a tkinter interface change the value of a variable and then close the interface, but I cannot seem to get it right. This is for a rock paper scissors game.

```
def rok():
    global choice
    choice=1     
    root.destroy  


rock_button = ttk.Button(root, text = "Rock", command=rok)
```

No error is raised when my code is run and I click the button, and the variable always has its value changed as expected when the button is pushed, but the window is never destroyed.

Why is the function not destroying the window, and how can I get it to?

I have only had about three hours total of python practice/learning so I apologize if any of the terminology I used was incorrect.

Comment: try: root.destroy()

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I feel a bit dumb now. Do you think this question is worth keeping up? or should I delete it? I am not sure how useful it could be to anyone else seeing as it was such a small thing.

Comment: happens to us all :), up to you I'd say. Correctly asked question but contribution is indeed questionable.